# grep return matching line and n lines before matching record

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a restricted bash (has grep and sed amongst other tools, but not awk) which I'm trying to use to quickly automate some routine work. I'm currently using "grep keyword filename -b3" and would like to figure out how to do this more efficiently within the very limited tools I have.

How do I use bash to grep for the symbol "111AA2026", get the "record" name 3 lines above the matching line including the matched line itself for an XML file like this:

```
<record name="111111H2" />
<items>
  <field name="Electronic Identifier" value="1"/>
  <field name="Symbol" value="111AA2026"/>
  <field name="Full Symbol" value="111AA202622MARFUT"/>
  <field name="System Identifier" value="1"/>
  <field name="System Identifier Description" value="Description"/>
</items>
<record name="111111N1" />
<items>
  <field name="Electronic Identifier" value="2"/>
  <field name="Symbol" value="111AA2026"/>
  <field name="Full Symbol" value="111AA202621JULFUT"/>
  <field name="System Identifier" value="2"/>
  <field name="System Identifier Description" value="Description"/>
</items>
<record name="111111Q1" />
<items>
  <field name="Electronic Identifier" value="3"/>
  <field name="Symbol" value="111AA2026"/>
  <field name="Full Symbol" value="111AA202621AUGFUT"/>
  <field name="System Identifier" value="3"/>
  <field name="System Identifier Description" value="Description"/>
</items>
<record name="111111U1" />
<items>
  <field name="Electronic Identifier" value="4"/>
  <field name="Symbol" value="111AA2026"/>
  <field name="Full Symbol" value="111AA202621SEPFUT"/>
  <field name="System Identifier" value="4"/>
  <field name="System Identifier Description" value="Description"/>
</items>
<record name="111111Z1" />
<items>
  <field name="Electronic Identifier" value="5"/>
  <field name="Symbol" value="111AA2026"/>
  <field name="Full Symbol" value="111AA202621DECFUT"/>
  <field name="System Identifier" value="5"/>
  <field name="System Identifier Description" value="Description"/>
</items>
```

Note that there are multiple different "Symbol" values in the actual file

Sample output

```
<record name="111111H2" />
 <field name="Symbol" value="111AA2026"/>
--
<record name="111111N1" />
 <field name="Symbol" value="111AA2026"/>
--
<record name="111111Q1" />
 <field name="Symbol" value="111AA2026"/>
--
<record name="111111U1" />
 <field name="Symbol" value="111AA2026"/>
--
<record name="111111Z1" />
 <field name="Symbol" value="111AA2026"/>
```

The key challenge I have is grepping a matching result that gives me the matching line and 3 lines above, and not so much about how to get the attributes of an XML file

Comment: Do you have `xmllint` or `Perl`?

Comment: no i don't have access to those within a restricted bash

Comment: @louisxie I know you've asked a (now deleted) question about transforming this same XML into some CSV lines. I thought it was a nice challenge for `sed`, so in case that interests you, I've created a script using just `sed` that does the transformation you wanted: https://gist.github.com/igstan/5ffddceba4a6f0516d93cd10ffce8582 There are probably better approaches to this problem, like using `awk`, but... it was a fun challenge :)

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan oh wao thank you sooo much!! yes I had that deleted as someone unhelpful closed my question. I wanted my answer very much and didn't want my next question to be closed again for being a duplicate, so I reposted it and rephased it. I'm reallly really grateful you helped with the next part of my trouble!

Comment: @louisxie glad I could help. Let me know if you have further questions on that script, since I know `sed` can be pretty daunting, but it's also quite fascinating.

Comment: Are you **sure** you don't have awk, maybe in a bin you didn't know about? Unlike `perl`, or XML tools, `awk` is one of the mandatory POSIX tools just like `grep`, `sed`, and `cat` - a system that doesn't have `awk` isn't a Unix system and if you were to create a system that's a subset of Unix it'd make a lot more sense to have awk without sed, grep, cat, etc. than to have those but no awk since awk can do what any of the rest of those tools can do.

Comment: @ed mortan, you might have missed the part that I only have access to a restricted bash. My guess is awk isn't allowed as it can be used for escaping a restricted shell

Comment: No, I saw that, I'm just surprised at what it's restricted TO - having a bunch of tools instead of 1 tool in a "restricted" environment doesn't make sense to me. Awk can't do any escaping that you couldn't do from sed. Oh well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it outputs something very similar to what you gave in the sample output.

```
cat temp.xml \
  | grep -B3 '"111AA2026"' \
  | sed -n '/<record/p;/"Symbol/p'
```

```
# The -n flag disables printing of all lines, which is what sed
# does by default, so we need to handle printing ourselves using
# the "p" command.
sed -n '
  # [p]rint all lines that contain: <record
  /<record/ p
  # [p]rint all lines that contain: "Symbol
  /"Symbol/ p
'
```

Comment: would you mind explaining how the sed part works?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/record/{:a;N;/Symbol/!ba;/111AA2026/s/(\n).*(\1.*)/\2\1--/p}' file
```

Gather up lines between `record` and `Symbol` and if those lines contain the literal `111AA2026`, print the first and last lines of the collection plus a delimiter `--`.

Alternative using grep only:

```
grep -B3 '111AA2026' file | grep 'record\|"Symbol"\|--'
```